# c++ create text fits edit box

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

Well..  I know that title is not that clear, I couldn't think of better one.
I wanna know how to do this...
when you have edit box and it only can show 10 characters.
Something like this

---

ssssssssss

---

let just say i have more than 10 characters.  Some of them will go in the back.
Like we have this string "123456789010" it will show just these ones "3456789010".
My problem is that some characters are small and don't take that much space and some do.
So i can't find a way to break the string and get some characters in the back.
any idea?

Comment: Um... that didn't make alot of sense did it?

Comment: No, it's not too clear to me. Are you using a resource file to program your edit box, or are you doing it programmatically (sorry, just trying to get at your question better)? Are you looking for a multi-line edit? Why do you exactly want to break the string and where do you want to put those characters?

Comment: I'm creating a edit box using directx. The Problem is that the edit box is only 50 px so i can' fit 8 f's or 4 w's. if i put 9 f's it won't look right, it will show that 1 extra f is on the border of the edit box.  so i'm trying to find a way to know if there is enough characters in edit box, if there is more they should be deleted

Comment: I am not too familiar with DirectX edit boxes, but it seems as though you are looking for something similar to WinAPI's ES_AUTOHSCROLL (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775464%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), correct?

Comment: um.. not really but it some like this this. ok here is an example, in your browser type this fsdfsdlkfjdsfdslfjsflksfjlskdfjslkfjsldkfjslfkjsfljflksjflsdfjslkfjslfkjslkfjsdlfkjsdflksjflskfjsldfkjsdlfkjsdfldjfsdfkljelkfjaleskfjlsekfjlksejflkejflekjflekfjlskfjlskfjeslkjfekljfleskfjslkfjslkfjsklfjselkfjsefksjflskfjlkefjslkefjselfsejflsfjlskefjlkaf  ok you only gonna see part of it and the rest of it is on the left hiding. that is what i'm trying to do when there is more characters that edit box can show some of it are on the left not showing.

Comment: just found a bug in stackoverflow

Comment: @ramilol Maybe you should shorten that "example"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the display-length of the string in your control (there are several function for that) and adjust the size of the control accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in Style type in `edit box` use `ES_MULTILINE` for use multiple lines.

```
edit1=CreateWindowA("edit","edit box",WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_BORDER|ES_MULTILINE,120,160,200,200,hWnd,(HMENU)IDI_EDIT,hInstance,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

you only want to see the far left or far right?

here is your string "0123456789"

you can only display 5 values due to pixel size of box....

do you want it to be "...56789" more like "56789"

or "01234..." more like "01234"?

Comment: i wanna see 56789,  well i don't know how many values i can display.  it all depends on the characters that user will put